# JDBC connection from Java stored procedure running in Oracle Database 12.2 is not working

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, java-stored-procedures

We are getting an error message when attempting to create an Oracle db connection from a java stored procedure running within an Oracle database. We have isolated to the connection and it is working with Oracle Database 12.1, running Java 1.7. Since upgrading to Oracle Database 12.2 and Java 1.8, we are getting the following error message.

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection 

Attempting to connect with: jdbc:oracle:thin@########
An error occurred in ###: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Here is the code we are using to test the connection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
    
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class RemoteDBTest {
    
    public static String remoteConnection()
     throws SQLException
    {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      String userId = "xxxx";
      String password = "xxxxx";
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/SID"; // Destination is a remote database. Actual host, port, and service have been replaced in this example.
      Connection conn = null;

      OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
      ods.setUser(userId);
      ods.setPassword(password);
      ods.setURL(url);
      System.out.println(url);
      System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
      try {
          conn = ods.getConnection();
      } catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
          throw e;
      }
      System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
      sb.append("Auto commit = " + conn.getAutoCommit());
      conn.close();
   
      return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
           System.out.println(remoteConnection());
        } catch (SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The only functioning work around at this point from Oracle support is to set the property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to `true`, however, when set via code, it increases the execution time of the connection to 9 seconds. We have attempted to set this property via command line and the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable, however, it doesn't seem to affect the JVM running the stored procedure.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Host OS: Windows Server 2016

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Note: This is not a duplicate of [IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574414/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection). Our connection parameters are correct and the connection is successful if we add `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");` to our code. However, as noted above, that introduces an unacceptable performance overhead.

Comment: @Abra Yes, it is a java stored procedure. It is not pl/sql.

Comment: @Abra There you go

Comment: @Abra - The question reads, `We are getting an error message when attempting to create an Oracle db connection from Java code...`.

Comment: @KentAnderson - As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/): `If IPv6 is available on the operating system, the underlying native socket will be an IPv6 socket. This allows Java applications to connect to, and accept connections from, both IPv4 and IPv6 hosts.

If an application has a preference to only use IPv4 sockets, then this property can be set to true. The implication is that the application will not be able to communicate with IPv6 hosts.`

Comment: @KentAnderson - You may find [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27119_01/doc.11113/e23126/installationandupgradeguideprintable36.html), [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-troubleshooting.html#GUID-5BC8E69F-F199-468C-8AB8-72D489F33029)  and [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.3/wlsrn/issues.html#GUID-A42A4025-4B26-485A-9BB5-BF36541ABD60) useful as well.

Comment: @KentAnderson - As per your edit, [IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574414/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection) doesn't answer your question. Therefore, I've opened the question again.

Comment: Why do you need to connect to another Oracle database from a java stored procedure? There are several ways for two Oracle instances to communicate, for example there is [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793). Is using a java stored procedure your only option?

Comment: Perhaps [Advanced Queuing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adque/index.html) is a possible option?

Comment: @Abra Thank you for the suggestions and help. Unfortunately, we have a significant amount of existing code using this type of connection.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using wrong URL "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/SID"

Shall be jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverhostname.com:1521/DB

@serverhostname.com hostname of oracle db
1521 is a port of your Db (1521 is default I think)
SID - DB shall be a SID of your database (ask your DB admin for correct one)

Comment: We are using the correct hostname, port, and database identifier. I used those values as placeholders in my posted code for privacy reasons.